# I need help merging this JavaScript WebGL Earth animate (rotate) function into TypeScript for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation, webgl-earth

Following these [instructions](https://github.com/webglearth/webglearth2/issues/108) I already have a WebGL Earth globe in an Angular component up and working.
But writing this WebGL Earth [animation (rotating) example](https://examples.webglearth.com/#animation) animate function in to the typescript Angular component throws all sorts of errors.
It's also important to include this [start and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347598/webgl-earth-restart-animation-at-current-location) at the same location into the animate (rotate) function.

So how to write this:

```
    var before = null;
    requestAnimationFrame(function animate(now) {
        var c = earth.getPosition();
        var elapsed = before? now - before: 0;
        before = now;
        earth.setCenter([c[0], c[1] + 0.1*(elapsed/30)]);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    });
```

In to typescript.

The trickiest part I'm finding is this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function animate(now) {
```

callback ? recursive function ? from JavaScript into TypeScript.
But also the

```
var before = null;
```

assignment.

I will post again with my next attempt/ update! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I came up with something suspiciously simple that seems ok.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
...

  earth:any;
  rotating: boolean = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
    this.rotate();
  }

  pauseAnimation(){
    this.rotating = !this.rotating;
  }

  rotate() {
    const observable = interval(10);
    observable.subscribe( () => {
      if (this.rotating) {
        let c = this.earth.getPosition();
        this.earth.setCenter([c[0], c[1] + 0.1]);
      }
    });
  }
```

...  =  missing code. 
The longitude coordinate just seems to loop round (-180 -- 180).
I think the observable/ interval should be paused as well, but it seems fine for now. And Much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

This would be the TypeScript equivalent.

```
let before: number | null = null;

function animate(now: number) {
  const c = earth.getPosition();
  const elapsed = before ? now - before : 0;
  before = now;
  earth.setCenter([c[0], c[1] + 0.1 * (elapsed / 30)]);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Comment: Thanks, it still throws errors (the function keyword shouldn't be there? and It's still confusing with the callback? with no argument. But thank you.  -- I've come up with something really simple. I'll post it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).